# Why is the unit code failing when results are the same?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

I have to compare 2 xmls for unit testing and if they match I have to pass the test. I used the XMLDiff patch technique and stored the result into a boolean "bIdentical". After that did the following:

```
        string result="";
        if(bIdentical)
            result="true";
        else
            result="false";
        object expectedFinal = "true";
        object actualFinal = result;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedFinal, actualFinal);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
```

Why is this failing though expectedEqual is the same as actualFinal? I debugged the code and saw both have the same string "true". Still its executing the line Assert.Inconclusive and test fails. please advice.

Comment: So, the test fails because `Assert.Inconclusive` fails?

Comment: You are doing a comparison by reference instead of by value. Why do you even convert a bool to a string and then to an object?

Comment: I am little confused here, isn't that expected from Assert.Inconclusive ? what m I missing here ?

Comment: Okay got it! that line was not required at all! thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `Assert.AreEqual(expectedFinal, actualFinal);` succeeds. After that line the next assert is executed. Because it is as Inconclusive, your test fails. Remove the last line and the test succeeds. You can have multiple asserts in one unittest. The test will execute them till it finds one that fails.